# Vue.js inject dynamically external dependencies

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a site in vue.js do with vue-cli. When the app starts, the /js/app.js file loads and executes vue. I load dependencies by adding links in my index.html like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3001/lib.umd.min.js"></script>
```

The dependencies this load, all is well. My problem is that I don't know the urls in advance. They are in a json file at the root of the site that I must read and then inject dynamically into the site. If in the main.js I do :

```
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.onload = function () {
    new Vue({
        router,
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
}
script.src = 'http://localhost:3001/lib.umd.min.js'
head.appendChild(script)
```

Dependencies are not understood but the link in the html exists. App Vue work well but not dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the mounted hook for your app:

```
mounted() {
 // get the scripts from your file and loop if needed
 // then for each one... 
 let myScript = document.createElement('script')
 myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://some-rl.js') // url from file goes here
 document.head.appendChild(myScript)
}
```

Comment: No it's same, script is not execute